# Where should I place the phpdoc.xml file?

Tags: php, phpdoc

phpdoc can be configured either using a .xml file or an .ini file.  The documentation is ambiguous, but it seems that using an .xml file is currently the preferred approach.  Agree?

Where should I place the .xml file?

According to http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/configuration.html...

> The easiest solution would be to place the configuration file in the
>   root of your project with the name: phpdoc.dist.xml.

Which directory do they refer to as "the root of your project"?  I've tried everything i.e.

```
/usr/share/pear/phpDocumentor, 
/var/www/phpDocumentor,
 /var/www,
```

and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I seem to be having the same issue. Are you using the phar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root of your project is where you put the code that you need to genereate the doc. example: you need to generate the doc for code inside `/var/www/example` directory, then the phpdoc.dist.xml. shoud be in it. It works just like `composer` and `phpunit`.

example again:

```
$ phpdoc -d ./src -t ./docs/api
```

phpdoc.dist.xml should bi in `./src`

Comment: Thanks egig.  So, when running phpdoc, do I also need to be in that same directory?  Otherwise, how dod phpdoc know which phpdoc.dist.xml to use?  Also, if I want to parse /var/www/thisDir and /var/www/thatDir, do I put it in /var/www?

Comment: `do I also need to be in that same directory?` no, but you have to specify `-d /your/src/path` option. `how do phpdoc know which phpdoc.dist.xml to use ?` the one that exist in `/your/src/path` . `do I put it in /var/www?` ... `$ phpdoc -d /var/www/thisDir  -t /var/www` and `$ phpdoc -d /var/www/thatDir  -t /var/www `

Comment: But http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/configuration.html states you don't need to type anything by `phpdoc` as all the necessary information is in the xml file.

Comment: yes, only `When you have added a configuration file`. I mean `do I also need to be in that same directory?` Not always. If you have path defined in your config file, then you don't need to `-d`  option.

Comment: I still haven't gotten this to work. But I am using a custom phar file. Would that affect anything?